# how to use js Promise to eliminate pyramid of doom

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

i'm trying to understand how to use js Promise api to refractor a code that has lots of nested IF.

example when getting JSON object from localstorage a normal code would look like

```
function $storage(key,default) {
  let json = localStorage.getItem(key);

  if(json === null) return default;

  try{  // <-- need try catch in case value was not valid json object
    json = JSON.parse(json); 
  } catch (e) {
    json = default;
  }
  return typeof json === 'object' ? json : default;
}
```

the readibility of this code is not that good. so i thought may be i can utilize js Promise to rewrite it into

```
function $storage (key, default) {
 let ret;

 let promise = new Promise( (y,n) => y(localStorage) )
 .then( ls => JSON.parse(ls.getItem(key)) )
 .then( json => typeof json === 'object' ? json : HOW_TO_THROW_ERROR() )
 //on more validation step if needed
 .then( json => typeof json === 'object' ? json : HOW_TO_THROW_ERROR() )
 .then( valid_json => { return = valid_json } )
 .catch( error => { ret = default; console.warn('json invalid',e); } );

 return ret;

}
```

now i want to know how can i throw an exception inside then so that the catch can caught it and execute default ?

is this valid usage of js promise of am i wasting performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Promise.reject()` to throw an error:

```
function $storage (key, default) {
 let ret;

 let promise = new Promise( (y,n) => y(localStorage) )
 .then( ls => JSON.parse(ls.getItem(key)) )
 .then( json => typeof json === 'object' ? json : Promise.reject("invalid json") )
 .then( valid_json => { return = valid_json } )
 .catch( err => { ret = default; console.warn(err.message); } );

 return ret;

}
```

Although I find the following more legible and idiomatic.

```
function $storage(key,default) {
  let json = localStorage.getItem(key);
  if(json === null ||  typeof json !== 'object') json = default;

  try{  
    json = JSON.parse(json); 
  } catch (e) {
    json = default;
  } finally {
  return json
  }
}
```

Promises are used, as you surely know, for asynchronous computation. Any other use might confuse other programmers.

Comment: Thank you for sharing an alternative. Is there a downside to use the 1st example other than the lack of legibility?

Answer (score 1):

You can use thrown to thrown the errors and then handle them in catch method

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success');
});

p1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "Success!"
  throw 'oh, no!';
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e); // "oh, no!"
}).then(function(){
  console.log('after a catch the chain is restored');
}, function () {
  console.log('Not fired due to the catch');
});

// The following behaves the same as above
p1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "Success!"
  return Promise.reject('oh, no!');
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e); // "oh, no!"
}).then(function(){
  console.log('after a catch the chain is restored');
}, function () {
  console.log('Not fired due to the catch');
});
```

But if thrown some errors in async functions the catch is never called.

```
// Errors thrown inside asynchronous functions will act like uncaught errors
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    throw 'Uncaught Exception!';
  }, 1000);
});

p2.catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e); // This is never called
});
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript you can use the keyword [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) to throw any error. 
Examples from MDN:

```
throw "Error2"; // generates an exception with a string value
throw 42;       // generates an exception with the value 42
throw true;     // generates an exception with the value true
throw new Error("Error");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function $storage (key, default) {
 let ret;

 let promise = new Promise( (y,n) => y(localStorage) )
 .then( ls => JSON.parse(ls.getItem(key)) )
 .then( json => typeof json === 'object' ? json : throw new Error("invalid json") )
 //on more validation step if needed
 .then( json => typeof json === 'object' ? json : throw new Error("invalid json") )
 .then( valid_json => { return = valid_json } )
 .catch( err => { ret = default; console.warn(err.message); } );

 return ret;

}
```

You could basically just do the following, because if the parse fails, it will be catched automatically.

```
function $storage (key, default) {
 let ret;

 let promise = new Promise( (y,n) => y(localStorage) )
 .then(ls => JSON.parse(ls.getItem(key)) )
 .then(valid_json => { return = valid_json } )
 .catch(err => { ret = default; console.warn(err.message); } );

 return ret;

}
```

Comment: problem is now $storage always return undefined i think because promise is resolved after the function return the value

Comment: you could return the promise instead and do a `then()` chain on the calling function. Promise is something that will be resolved at a later time and therefore a synchronous return will not work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is just about `JSON.parse`, wrapping it in a more usable function you get something like:

```
function safeParse(x) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(x);
    } catch(e) {
        // Log the problem
        return null;
    }
}

function parmval(key, defval) {
    var json = safeParse(localStorage.get(key));
    return (typeof json === "object") ? json : defval;
}
```

Promises are about asynchronous operations, not IFs.